How many different types of polynomials of degree $n$ are there?
Let $0 < a,b,c < 1$. A cubic equation of the form $ax^3 - bx - x - b = 0$ has the property that the absolute values of its roots always satisfy the triangle inequality while the equation $ax^3 + ax^2 -cx-1 = 0$ has the property that absolute values of its roots never satisfy the triangle inequality. Denote the structure the first equation by ordered tuple $(a, -b, -1, -b)$ and the second by $(a, a, -c, -1)$. We see that these structures exhibit certain properties such as always satisfying the triangle inequality or never satisfying it. Given a certain property and an $n$, we can ask what structures of a equation of degree $n$ and real coefficients has this property. But this question, leads to the natural question - given $n$,

Question: How many distinct structures can equation of degree $n$ with real coefficients have? (Preferable a closed form representation in the form $f(n)$)

To answer this question, we need to define what qualifies as a valid structure any we have $0 < a,b,c < 1$ in the above examples.
Let $\alpha_n x^n + \alpha_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + \alpha_1 x + \alpha_0 = 0$ where all the coefficients are all real. We standardize the coefficients in the interval $[-1,1]$, by dividing each term by $\max(|\alpha_n|, |\alpha_{n-1}|, \ldots, |\alpha_0|)\times \frac{\alpha_n}{|\alpha_n|}$. This results in a Kac polynomial and which can be written as
$$
a_n x^n \pm a_{n-1}x^{n-1} \pm \cdots \pm a_1 x \pm a_0 = 0
$$
where $a_k \in [0,1]$, $k = 1,2, \ldots, n$ and denote this equation by the ordered tuple $(a_n, \pm a_{n-1},\ldots, \pm a_0)$ where $\pm a_k$ is the coefficient of $x^k$. Clearly, at least one of the coefficients $a_k$ must have magnitude $1$ and $a_n a_0 \ne 0$ otherwise the degree of the equation will reduce to $n-1$.
Standardization provides a framework to analyze the structure or family of a given equation, as illustrated through the following examples. In each of the cubic equation $(0.5, 0.5, -0.4, -1)$ and $(0.99, 0.99, -0.99, -1)$, the coefficients of $x^3$ and $x^2$ are equal and positive, the coefficient of $x$ is negative, and the constant term is $-1$. We say that both these equation has the same structure $(u, u, -v, -1)$, where $u,v$ are variables representing the coefficients which can take values in $(0,1)$. Thus we can say, $(0.5, 0.5, -0.4, -1)$ is an example member of this family or structure.
Properties of a structure

${\textbf{Explicitness of magnitude $0$ and $1$}}$: Apart from coefficients explicitly specified as having a value of $0$ in the structure, no other coefficient can have a magnitude of $0$. This is because prior to standardization, if the coefficient with magnitude $0$ occurred in two or more terms, then after standardization, there would be two or more standardized coefficients with a magnitude of $0$ so, the structure of such an equation would inherently include two or more coefficients with magnitude $0$. Hence for eg, the family $(a, 0, -1, -1)$ is distinct from $(a, b, -1, -d)$. Also if $0$ is not mandated to be explicitly mentioned in the structure than it can lead to equations of a lower degree. For example, the structure $(a,-1,\pm b)$ represents a quadratic equation only if $b > 0$ but for $b=0$, $(a,-1, 0)$ reduces to the linear equation $(a,-1)$. By the same reasoning, apart from coefficients explicitly specified as having a value of $\pm 1$ in the structure, no other coefficient can have a magnitude of $1$. Hence for eg the family $(a, a, -1, -1)$ is distinct $(a, a, -1, -d)$.

${\textbf{Lexiographical ordering to avoid duplicates}}$: Consider the following sets $A = \{(a, b, c, 1), (a, c, b, 1)\}$, $B = \{(a, b, b, 1), (a, c, c, 1)\}$ and $C = \{(1, a, a), (1, b, b)\}$. In each set, all the member equations of the first tuple can be also represented by the second tuple. So which one should we consider as a valid structure and which one a duplicate? To avoid such ambiguity, we need a well defined rule, using the variables/alphabets lexicographically. If $u_1 = a, u_2 = b$, $u_k$ be the $k$-th alphabet then any the first appearance of alphabet in a structure $u_k$ can only be $k$-th position (from the left). Thus if $a$ does not appear in the first position, then it cannot appear anywhere else in the structure. Likewise, if the first appearance of $b$ is not in the 2nd position then it cannot appear anywhere in the structure. It follows from this rule that $(a, b, c, 1)$ valid while $(a, c, b, 1)$ is a duplicate, $(a, b, b, 1)$ is valid while $(a, c, c, 1)$ is a duplicate and, $(1,b,b)$ is valid while $(1,a,a)$ is a duplicate of $(1,b,b)$. This also explains why $(1,c,c), (a,0,1,b), (1,a,b,c)$ etc are all invalid.


Eg 1: List of all linear families
There are $6$ distinct families/types/structures of linear equations
$$
(1,1), (1,-1), (1,b), (1,-b), (a,1), (a,-1).
$$
corresponding to the linear equations
$$
x+1=0, x-1=0, x+b=0, x-b=0, ax+1=0, ax-1=0
$$
Notice that $(a, \pm b)$ is invalid since at least one of the coefficient must be $+1$ or $-1$. Similarly $(1, \pm a)$ and $(1, \pm a)$ are invalid since they will result in a duplicates of $(1,\pm b)$.
Eg 2: List of all quadratic families
There are $46$ distinct families of quadratic equations:

Question: How many different structures does an equation of degree $n$ has?
My progress: Let $f(n)$ be the number of distinct families of equation of degree $n$. The trivial upper bound is for $n \ge 2$
$$
f(n) < 4(n+2)\prod_{k=3}^{n+1}(2k+1) 
= (8n^2 + 28n + 24)\prod_{k=3}^{n}(2k+1)
$$
But we can improve this by noting that $a$ appears in the structure only if the first term is $a$. This adjustment gives
$$
f(n) < (4n^2 + 24n + 22)\prod_{k=3}^{n}(2k+1)
$$
If my calculations are right, then $f(3) = 382$.

A few questions: Why is $(-1,1)$ not a distinct family of linear equations? And $(-1,-1)$ and $(-1,b)$? Why are $(1,b)$ and $(1,-b)$ distinct? And for the quadratics, why is $(1,0,c)$ not in $(1,b,c)$? And similarly $(1,0,-1)$ not in $(1,b,-1)$? Etcetera.

Surely it will not have the $x$ term when $b=0$?

Then please clarify your definition, until then you have my downvote.

Also, what is the point of this classification?

Sure. Please clarify the question.

@Servaes If the new edits to the question address your queries, shall we clean up the thread. I have deleted my replies.

Normalization make the coeff of the largest power of $x$ positive so $(-1,-1)$, $(-1,b)$ are duplicates of $(1,1)$, $(1,b)$. $0$ needs to be explicitly mentioned else if the last/first term is $0$ the polynomial reduces in degree. The points/motivation comes from study of structures; it turns out that certain structures exhibit properties which are inherited by all its members. Eg all the roots cubic equations of the type $(,−,−1,−)$ have absolute value which fail the triangle inequality. Similarly there are other structures whose modulus of roots always satisfy the triangle inequality.

The normalization you specify does not make the coefficient of the largest power of $x$ positive. For example, if you have $-2x-2=0$ then you divide by
$$\max(\alpha_n, \alpha_{n-1}, \ldots, \alpha_0)\times \frac{\alpha_n}{|\alpha_n|}=\max(-2,-2)\times\frac{-2}{|-2|}=2,$$
and so you get the type $(-1,-1)$.

@Servaes Yes you are right, I missed the absolute value sign inside the max function. It should be $$\max(|\alpha_n|, |\alpha_{n-1}|, \ldots, |\alpha_0|)\times \frac{\alpha_n}{|\alpha_n|}$$

In my deleted answer, I missed that coordination among the fractional entries matters, i.e. $(1,a,a)$ and $(1,a,b)$ are considered distinct (as are $(1,a,-a)$ and $(1,a,-b)$). In hindsight this is clearly implied by your examples, but it might help to formulate the combinatorial problem more directly.

With the normalization and distinguishing of 1s, you're saying you care which coefficient is the largest. But you don't care about the relative magnitudes of the other nonzero coefficients? Why assign $2x^2+3x+4$ and $3x^2+2x+4$ to the same family but $4x^2+3x+2$ and $3x^2+4x+2$ to different families?

@Karl Also note that $(1,\pm a, \pm a)$ and $(1,\pm a, \pm b)$ would both be invalid as they would violate the lexicographical ordering in the naming condition. The valid form of $(1,\pm a, \pm a)$ is $(1,\pm b, \pm b)$ and the valid form of $(1,\pm a, \pm b)$ would be $(1,\pm b, \pm c)$.

Since we divide by the magnitude and sign of the largest coeff with the largest magnitude, $2x^2+3+4$ and $3x^2 + 2x + 4$ has the same structure $(a,b,1)$ but the structure of $4x^2 + 3x +2$ is $(1,b,c)$ while that of $3x^2 + 4x + 2$ is $(a,1,c)$ i.e. they have two different structures.

Right, your families distinguish which coefficient is largest and which coefficients are equal to each other but do not otherwise distinguish between $<$ and $>$. An interesting choice and an interesting counting problem!
